# Distribute pre-compiled python extension module with distutils

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

Quick one today: I'm learning the in's and out's of Pythons distutils library, and I would like to include a python extension module (.pyd) with my package. I know of course that the recommended way is to have distutils compile the extension at the time the package is created, but this is a fairly complex extension spanning many source files and referencing several external libs so it's going to take some significant playing to get everything working right.

In the meantime I have a known working build of the extension coming out of Visual Studio, and would like to use it in the installer as a temporary solution to allow me to focus on other issues. I can't specify it as a module, however, since those apparently must have an explicit .py extension. How could I indicate in my setup.py that I want to include a pre-compiled extension module?

(Python 3.1, if it matters)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a manifest template:

http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

Comment: As of writing, a working URL for this is https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by overriding Extension.build_extension:

```
setup_args = { ... }
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    class my_build_ext(build_ext):
        def build_extension(self, ext):
            ''' Copies the already-compiled pyd
            '''
            import shutil
            import os.path
            try:
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)))
            except WindowsError, e:
                if e.winerror != 183: # already exists
                    raise


            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(this_dir, r'..\..\bin\Python%d%d\my.pyd' % sys.version_info[0:2]), self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name))

    setup_args['cmdclass'] = {'build_ext': my_build_ext }

setup(**setup_args)
```

Comment: Very nice! The answer should also mention the extension entry that goes into `setup(..)`: `ext_modules=[Extension("_my_extension", sources=[])]`

Comment: Thank you Kevin; very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue while building an extension library using Python 3.7, CMake 3.15.3 and Swig 4.0.1 with Visual Studio 2017. The build system generates three files: mymodule.py, _mymodule.lib and _mymodule.pyd. After a bunch of trial and error, I found the following combination to work:

1. Create a 'setup.cfg' file that specifies that you are installing a package; e.g:

```
    [metadata]
    name = mymodule
    version = 1.0

    [options]
    include_package_data = True
    package_dir=
        =src
    packages=mymodule
    python_requires '>=3.7'

    [options.package_data]
    * = *.pyd
```

2. Change CMake to create a distribution directory structure as follows:

```
    setup.py
    setup.cfg
    src/
        mymodule/
                 __init__.py
                 _mymodule.pyd
```

3. The 'setup.py' file is then trivial:

```
    setup()
```

This requires having CMake rename the 'mymodule.py' output file to '**init**.py'. I did this with the 'install' command in CMake:

```
    install (TARGETS ${SWIG_MODULE_${PROJECT_NAME}_REAL_NAME} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/src/${PROJECT_NAME}")
    install (FILES 
            setup.py
            setup.cfg
            DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist"
    )

    install (FILES
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.py
            DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/src/${PROJECT_NAME}"
            RENAME "__init__.py"
```

I believe that the key secret to having this work was to restructure the build output as a Python package rather than trying to have setup use the default build output of as a Python script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is what has worked out for me.
I have changed the name of the module, just for the sake of a simple example.

**My setup is:**
Visual Studio 2017 Project which builds an extension with a final file name myextension.pyd

I then locally created the stubs for this module using stubgen from mypy module.

This is my file tree

```
myextension/__init__.pyi
myextension/submodule.pyi
setup.py
myextension.pyd
```

And this is the contents of `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, Distribution


class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def has_ext_modules(foo):
        return True


setup(
    name='myextension',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='myextension Wrapper',
    packages=['', 'myextension'],
    package_data={
        'myextension': ['*.pyi'],
        '': ['myextension.pyd'],
    },
    distclass=BinaryDistribution
)
```

After running `pip wheel .` I get a pretty nice wheel containing the extensions, along with the required stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using package_data: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript#installing-package-data

Comment: package_data does not honor directory structure of precompiled modules.